# Near natural lighting with softbox wattage between 2400 to 2700?

Tags: dslr, lighting, video-recording, greenscreen

I record video with a large window as a softbox during the day, but I want to record during the night keeping those nice ambient shadows and even lighting.

I'm planing to buy a 3 piece softbox kit. I currently have DSLR with 50 mm f 1.8 and 80 mm f1.4 lenses which give a nice light aperture. The more natural the light is the better.

Here's a sample of my setup with natural light (large window, no additional lights):

I found these two kits that caught my attention, my budget is around 200 bucks.

ePhoto 2400:
http://goo.gl/0GfWdf

ePhoto 2700:
http://goo.gl/6Wov5S

What is the best wattage between these two for a near natural lighting? If not what is the right ammount of wattage to archive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wattage has nothing to do with achieving natural lighting.  The amount of diffusion and placement does.  More light is ALWAYS better because it results in more signal to the camera and more options as far as ISO, aperture and shutter speed.

Nothing you setup with artificial lights (particularly on your budget) will come close to the level of the sun on even a cloudy day.  This doesn't matter though as long as you provide enough light for the camera to pick it up and spread it out through diffusers and light placement and reflectors such that you get a natural look.

I'd suggest reading some on 3 point lighting if you want more information on light placement and get the biggest diffusers you can, though on your budget, you will be hard pressed to get even a decent 3 point light kit, let alone any kind of diffusers.  (A decent large diffuser alone will run over $100.)  Your best bet is to put all the money in to the best light kit you can get and get diffusers later.  Proper three point lighting will still be fairly natural looking.

Comment: What do you think about this softbox, it seems large enough:
http://goo.gl/lSVm9t

Comment: @GabrielMeono - They might get the job done, but they are CFLs which are going to do anything but natural light.  They aren't dimmable(so you will have to use distance to adjust brightness) and the light generated will likely have some odd properties due to being florescent lighting.